# Outlook constantly repair itself

Tags: exchange, outlook

I have a XP PC with Outlook 2003 connected to SBS2003/Exchange 2003 SP2 (75GB Limit on Exch Store).
  Outlook constantly hangs when trying to forward ANY email. So whenever I tried to restart Outlook, it goes thru several minutes of repair, but the same problem continues.
  When I look at .OST file, the file size is over 10GB. Outlook is NOT running in Cached mode. When I checked Exchange Mailbox size, it was 10,448,392 KB with 74,365 items.

So I am thinking that possible causes are:
 (1) Damaged Profile
 (2) Outlook 2003 corrupted 
 (3) This particular user's mailbox size is too big for Outlook 2003 to handle
 (4) This user's mailbox in Exchange Server is corrupted.

As a temporary solution, I set up Remote Desktop session to SBS2011/DC ( I know it is not recommended, but I did not have time to troubleshoot onsite this morning) and in RDP session the user is using Outlook 2003. At least it has not crashed and the user can forward emails.

What do you think is causing the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you can just rename the .ost files and, if running in cached mode, outlook will just regenerate them next time it's run. Also office 2003 includes tools to check and repair both .ost (cache) and .pst (local mailbox) files.

Answer (score 1):

As Dan pointed out in the comment above, try renaming your .ost files and see if that resolves the issue.  The fact that Outlook works fine via RDP suggests that the problem is the user's local install.

(Since you already know your RDP workaround is not recommended this will be my only reference to it.)